# I want to make a side menu, and change the class while clicking

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I want to make a side menu, and change the class when clicking.

When i click on the "li" with no class="active", i want the jquery to add a class on the empty

and remove it from the othes "li". and i want to use Html.ActionLink only.

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "ach" })
    </li>
    <li>
         @Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home", new { @class = "ach" })
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "ach" })
    </li>

</ul>
```

```
    javascript which i used is:



 $('.ach').on('click', function () {
    debugger;
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: When you click on the link, your redirected to another page - there is no point setting the class in the current view (you have already left it)

Comment: but i have side menu as layout for all the pages. side menu will be there even if redirects to other page. i want this class change to happen on side menu.

Comment: Yes I know - but you have left the current page - you need to set the class in the the page your have redirect to, not the current one!

Comment: ok, i understand your point, so can you suggest me any work around to resolve this.

Comment: Read the duplicate

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "ach",id="homeLink" })
    </li>
    <li>
         @Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home", new { @class = "ach",id="aboutUsLink" })
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "ach" ,id="contactUsLink"})
    </li>

</ul>

 $('.ach').on('click', function (event) {
    debugger;
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    var id = event.target.id;
    $('#'+id).addClass('active');   

});
```

Comment: That is doing just exactly what OP current code is doing. Suggest you read the comments in the question.

Comment: this solution didn't work for me.